# Change style of basic states in tikz-uml package

Tags: tikz-uml

I'm currently trying to create a uml activity diagram using the tikz-uml package. However, I would like my uml activities to have a simple body instead of the "rectangle split"-like body they have now.

Desired style of activities:
[image: Desired style of activities]

Current style:
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \umlbasicstate [y=-10, rectangle] {I am a state}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I've tried changing line 2988 of tikz-uml.sty from

> \tikzstyle{tikzuml state style}=[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, rounded corners, inner xsep=1.5ex]

to

> \tikzstyle{tikzuml state style}=[rectangle, rounded corners, inner xsep=1.5ex]

but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mix `tikz-uml` nodes with regular, customizable `tikz` nodes. In the example below a style is defined for a simple state, to connect to the uml nodes.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\tikzset{singlestate/.style={draw,fill=yellow!20, rounded corners}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\umlstateinitial[name=initial]
\node[singlestate] at (5,0) (create){Create ticket};
\umlstatedecision[y=-3,x=5,name=decision]
\node[singlestate] at (1,-3)(reproduce){Reproduce issue};
\node[singlestate] at (10,-3)(update){Update ticket};
\umltrans{initial}{create}
\umltrans{create}{decision}
\umltrans{update}{decision}
\umltrans{decision}{reproduce}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

## There are no package for activity diagrams!

You're trying to use [TikZ-UML](https://perso.ensta-paris.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/) to draw an [activity diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_diagram), but, to quote [their documentation](https://perso.ensta-paris.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/var/files/html/web-tikz-uml-userguidech1.html#x3-20001):

> the package contains definitions of complete class diagrams, use case diagrams, sequence diagrams, state diagrams and component diagrams

So, this package *was not designed to support activity diagram*!
Its "competitors", [pgf-umlcd](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf-umlcd) and [pgf-umlsd](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf-umlsd), support only class and sequence diagrams (respectively).

All of those are examples of UML diagrams, but they are different from activity diagrams.

As far as I know, there are no class for activity diagram, but you can find multiple examples on-line, or easily construct your own.

## My Example

```
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} % Default family: serif
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
  initial/.style={circle, fill},
  decision/.style={diamond, black, draw},
  action/.style={rectangle, draw, rounded corners},
  arrow/.style={draw, -{Latex[length=3mm]}, thick}
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm]
% Frame
\draw [rounded corners] (-4,-1.5) rectangle (7, -8.5);
\node (title) at (5.2, -2) {\textbf{Teaching a class}};

% Nodes
\node[initial] (initial) at (0,-1) {};
\node[action, below of = initial] (ask)  {Ask for questions};
\node[decision, below of= ask] (decision1)  {};
\node[action, below left = 1cm and 1cm of decision1] (answer) {Answer question};
\node[action, right = 2.3cm of decision1] (intro) {Introduce class};
\node[decision, below of=intro] (decision2)  {};
\node[action, below left = 1cm and 1cm of decision2] (quiz) {Distribute quiz};
\node[action, below right = 1cm and 1cm of decision2] (class) {Start class};

% Arrow
\draw [arrow] (initial) -- (ask);
\draw [arrow] (ask) -- (decision1);
\draw [arrow] (decision1) -- node[above, pos=1pt]{[Question]} ++(-2cm, 0) -| (answer);
\draw [arrow] (answer) --  ++(2cm, 0) -| (decision1);
\draw [arrow] (decision1) -- node[above, pos=.4pt]{[No question]} (intro);
\draw [arrow] (intro) -- (decision2);
\draw [arrow] (decision2) -- node[above, pos=1pt]{[Quiz]} ++(-2cm, 0) -| (quiz);
\draw [arrow] (decision2) -- node[above, pos=.7pt]{[No quiz]} ++(2cm, 0) -| (class);

% Etc.
\draw[thick] (quiz) -- ++(0, -1);
\draw[dotted, thick] ($ (quiz)+(0,-1)$) -- ++(0, -.33);
\draw[thick] (class) -- ++(0, -1);
\draw[dotted, thick] ($ (class)+(0,-1)$) -- ++(0, -.33);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

will give you:

[image]

## Other Examples

[How to draw automaton as an Activity Diagram [TikZ]?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/342119/34551)

[image]

---

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/tikz-uml2-activity-diagram-and-mathematical-block-diagram/trdrdbdgryjf

[image]

---

http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/android/

[image]